# Ecommerce framework for mobile app

Tags: open-source, api, ecommerce, mobile

I have an e-commerce app, where we sell the stuff within the app.

What I basically want is the features for Shopify output into an API which I can integrate in my app. Unfortunately, Shopify doesn't seem to have support for mobile applications.

I know there are dozens of e-commerce frameworks, but most seem to be for websites and not apps.

- Support for manual payment (i.e. COD, bank transfer, or payment via SMS/telcos)
- Support for online payment, but not mandatory
- Tracking status of orders - paid, payment approved, delivery status, after sales support
- Tracking products and stock
- Sales reports, but not mandatory
- Documentation doesn't take longer to read than developing the system from scratch